# Rake is not working. The error states that there is a problem calling rake due to RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debian, rake

Rake is not working. The error states that there is a problem calling rake due to RVM.

> rake aborted!
>   No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

I've screenshot the problem.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: What output are you expecting? If you run `rake` in a folder *that's not configured to use `rake`*, then you'll see that error. (Which makes total sense -- what else could you expect to see, other than an error?)

Comment: If you want to configure `rake` for use within a new project, then you can start by running `rake init`, or just by writing a `Rakefile` manually - as shown in the README: https://github.com/ruby/rake#usage

Comment: My best guess, given the limited information I have (you've tagged this as a "ruby on rails" question, but the screenshot shows you're in the **home folder (`~`)** of your computer), is that you may just need to change directory (`cd`) into the folder that your rails project is in, before running `rake`. Also, by the way, the command you're looking for is `rake -T`, not `rake -t`.

Comment: Try `rvm get stable`

Comment: Really appreciate your reply man. But when  I ran rake -T in my rails, lib directory  I'm  still getting an error which states: "rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/dave/Co/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dave/Co/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/home/dave/Co/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dave/Co/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/dave/Co/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

"

Comment: @fool-dev, thank you for inlining the image, but note that it's best to simply remove the fluff instead of arranging the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `Rails` project structure

```
--project_name
   --app
   --bin 
   --config
   --db 
   --lib
   --log
   --public 
   --test 
   --tmp 
   --vendor
   --config.ru
   --Gemfile
   --Gemfile.loc
   >>--Rakefile
   --READNE.md
```

When I run `rake -t` without project then it's showing the error like

```
:~/workspace $ rake -t

No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:698:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

but when I run `rake -t` inside `Rails` project then it's working like

```
:~/workspace/recipies (master) $ rake -t

** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
** Execute default
Run options: --seed 14039

# Running:

..E
```

That means on your hand the `Rakefile` not found anywhere. SO you need to run this inside project where `Rakefile` exists.

***Note:*** You can use `rake -t` or [`rails -t`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails). Since Rails `5.0+` has `rake` commands built into the `rails` executable, `bin/rails` is the new default for running commands.

Comment: Does any help with this answer?